# How to make an icon for the new custom component in SceneBuilder (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx, icons, scenebuilder

After solved my problem of importing a new custom component in Scenebuilder [Custom control in Scenebuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014043/i-cant-open-a-fxml-with-scenebuilder-with-a-custom-component-resolved), I would like to know how to display a TableView (for example) icon in the Custom section instead of the icon showing the question mark in SceneBuilder

Thanks for your help